# How would you find a substring in xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I need to find an element in selenium 2 and I know that the link i'm looking for contains some defined text that I got in a varible. So this is how the link is:

```
<a id="ctl00_content_list_gvOtherSchemas_ctl02_lbViewSchema"
  href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
   WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$content$list$gvOtherSchemas$ctl02
     $lbViewSchema&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, &quot;&quot;,
     &quot;https://test/page.aspx?_InfoPath_Sentinel=1&amp;
   case=2011-015196&amp;name=MyCase&amp;version=2&amp;p=PPC1&amp;cc=ANSOEG&amp;
   py=2011&amp;rn=CR274&amp;c=0&amp;st=DRAFT&amp;oo=1&amp;sc=SC001&amp;hln=&amp;
   tl=31-12-2011 23:59:59&amp;sa=&amp;sai=&amp;san=&quot;, false, true))"
>MyCase</a>
```

And I want to look for the text: "case=2011-015196" by an xpath expression.

Comment: This question doesn’t even begin to make sense. Please at least make some effort to explain what you’re trying to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "locate"? You said initially you wanted to find the *element* that contains the given text (in this case, the `<a>` element); but then you asked how to locate the text in the postback, which suggests looking for the position of a substring within a string.

Comment: Sorry if that did not make sense, let me try to write it more clear.
There should make more sense now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more specific expression that looks for the `a` element whose `href` attribute contains the target string:

```
//a[contains(@href, '2011-015196')]
```

Or, more specifically:

```
//a[contains(@href, 'case=2011-015196')]
```

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to find the element that contains some given text, in my
>   case it's the text 2011-015196

Use this XPath:

```
//*[@*[contains(., '2011-015196')]]
```

> how would I locate the text in that postback with Xpath?

Use this:

```
string-length(substring-before(//*/@*[contains(., '2011-015196')],
                               '2011-015196'))
```

This will tell you the offset of `2011-015196` within the attribute that contains it.

Comment: Thanks LarsH your suggestion also works! What I meant was that I need to locate the link as a webelement in Selenium 2 so that i can click on it. I got alot of elements on the page that looks like the one I posted, so i needed to select the one with the right text.

Comment: +1 - I suspected the OP was looking for a  specific `a` element, but your answer definitely deserves an upvote.

Comment: @lwburk: thanks for the vote. Kudos to you for understanding the specifics not (initially) given in the question.

Comment: @LarsH - A lot of times I'm just trying to provide a slightly different answer, because beginners aren't really sure how to ask for what they want. It can sometimes be a bit of a guess and I don't really care about up-votes, as long as somebody finds the answer useful. Obviously, yours could have easily been the one accepted.